# Correct preposition for 'feature'

Tags: prepositions

Which preposition would follow the verb 'feature'? For instance, which would be correct?

> "A, B and C feature ***in*** the top 5 positions"

or

> "A, B and C feature ***at*** the top 5 positions"

I'm leaning towards ***in*** but just want to confirm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The preposition used is not affected by the verb used, but by where the action is directed.

For example one can run *in* a race, and one can run *at* a wall.

So it is similar with the verb *feature*. One can feature in a performance or feature at a place. E.g.

> Fred Astaire and Ginger Rogers feature in Shall We Dance.

or

> [...the only exception being the tip of a spear featuring at the upper left corner [of the image]...](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=1hG4q10O1LQC&pg=PA42&dq=%22featuring+at%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=YKgKT53nMcT08QPxvYHDAQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22featuring%20at%22&f=false)

So the question you need to ask is are A, B and C *in* something or *at* something? The answer lies in the word *position*. One can **both** be *at* a position, and *in* a position. This can be confirmed by looking at [the definition of at](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/at) which can be defined as *in, on or near*.

However it is most usual to write that something is *in* a position, with respect to ranking, as can be seen from this NGram:

[image: NGram of "at first position" vs "in first position"]

So to be easily understood by the most people I recommend using:

> A, B and C feature in the top 5 positions

Comment: Some editors and style guides are pickier about prepositions. CMS 16 has a section (5.191: "List of words and the prepositions construed with them") which assigns specific prepositions to some verbs.

Answer (score 1):

I would say **in** but I can't seem to find the documentation to back it up. Another option would be to say:

```
"A, B, and C hold three of the top five positions"
```

But admittedly this does not use **feature**.

Answer (score 1):

The first one is correct.For example- "Actress X is featured in the upcoming movie xyz".

Answer (score 0):

In your sentence, *in* makes more sense.  It's a matter of physical metaphors.

Do you consider the number 1 position a place that *A*, *B* or *C* can occupy?  (*At the top of the heap.*, as it were.)  In that case, use *at*.

Do you consider a position as being a slot in a table, into which *A*, *B* or *C* can be inserted?  In that case, it's better to use *in*.

In your case, your use of the words *feature* and *position* suggest the latter metaphor, so use *in*.